# How to get exact type of generic property from generic key

Tags: typescript

I have a function signature that today looks like this:

```
getProperty<T extends HTMLElement>(name: keyof T): Promise<T[keyof T]>;
```

I'm building Web Components that extend HTMLElement, say that I've added a property called `rows` which is of type `Row[]`.
If I call it like this (in some test util):

```
const rows = componentWrapper.getProperty<TableComponent>('rows');
```

The type of `rows` becomes a union of all possible types from the keys in TableComponent, which is how I'd expect `keyof` to work (so using it for the name argument makes sense).

What I want to achieve is to infer the type of `rows` to be `Row[]` by typing the return as something other than `Promise<T[keyof T]>`, how can I get the type of the property being grabbed based on the name argument?

Comment: can you add componentWrapper implementation?
In general what you are looking for is something ike this: `getProperty<T extends HTMLElement, K extends keyof T>(el: T, name: K): Promise<T[K]>`

Comment: I will try that, but does that mean I have to always supply the key both in the argument list as well in the generic arguments list? Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript can determine a type by input args. The next will work `getProperty(document.createElement('a'), 'href')`

Comment: I see, that doesn't work in my real case but at least I learnt how it might work, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Artem Bozhko wrote in the comments, this works:

```
getProperty<T extends HTMLElement, K extends keyof T>(el: T, name: K): Promise<T[K]>
```

With this you can also call the function without the generic parameter list since TypeScript will infer the types for T and K from the argument list.